# Magento 1 - Pass multiple variables to view

Tags: magento-1, blocks, extensions, custom-block, programming

We can pass a variable to a .phtml view file like this:

```
$currentTime = date("H:i", time());
$someValue = 123;

$this->loadLayout();

$this->getLayout()
    ->getBlock('newsletter_popup')
    ->assign('currentTime', $currentTime);

$this->renderLayout();
```

But how to pass multiple variables?

How can I pass `$someValue` too?

---

In Laravel it works like this:

```
return $view->with('currentTime', $currentTime)->with('someValue', $someValue);
```

Does it work like this in magento too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$foo = array();
$foo['currentTime'] = date("H:i", time());
$foo['someValue'] = 123;

$this->loadLayout();

$this->getLayout()
    ->getBlock('newsletter_popup')
    ->assign('foo', $foo);

$this->renderLayout();
```